# How can I use a ternary statement to simplify this code?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

In my first if statement, it checks to see if a word from the array `food` and `window[items]` appears in the text. In my second if statement, it checks to see if a word from the array `window[items]` appears in the text

Note that which if statement is run depends on whether or not the array `authors` is empty - the first statement will run if it isn't empty and the second will run if it is empty.

```
if(food.length > 0 && food.some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)) && window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text))) {
   ele[i].style.display = "block";
}else{
   ele[i].style.display = "none";  
}

if(food.length < 1 && window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text))) {
   ele[i].style.display = "block";
}else{
   ele[i].style.display = "none";  
}
```

I have tried simplifying this code by using a ternary operator, but it returns this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

```
if((food.length > 0 ? food.some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text))) && window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text))) {
   ele[i].style.display = "block";
}else{
   ele[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: can you share [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The syntax error is telling you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: *hint* ternary operator is this, `(condition evaluated true) ? action for true : action for false`

Comment: are you sure using ternary operator in this way would simplify the code? In my opinion it would rather make it harder to read in exchange for just few lines of code less

Comment: @Azanx Would you suggest keeping what I already have?

Comment: @TheCodesee , yes, for me it looks cleaner. You can try using nested if statements for some of the conditions. (for example, third condition in first statement looks to be the same as second condition in second statement), I don't know what's the relation with the `food.length` part though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the condition is: if (`food` is empty **or** the tag text contains any of `food`) **and** the tag text contains any of the `window[items]` :

```js
ele[i].style.display = (!food.length || food.some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)))
          && window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)) ? "block" : "none";
```

Comment: Cheers, this solved it! By the way, I further simplified it by creating the variable `var verify = text => tag.textContent.includes(text);` and then just calling `window[items].some(verify)` and `food.some(verify);`

Comment: Are you able to explain how by placing the condition inside parenthesis, it works, please?

Comment: I wanted to add alternative with a function for the repeating `.some` too, but it ended up longer. The syntax is `result = condition ? result if truthy : result if falsy`. The parentheses are used only to give the or operator `||` precedence over the and operator `&&`

Comment: Just so I understand right, the condition `(!food.length || food.some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)))` only runs if `!food.length` isn't true?

Comment: yes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators. You can try it with for example `!1 || console.log(1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by accumulation of two statements and checking with an  OR (||) condition. Something like

```
      ele[i].style.display = (food.length > 0 && food.some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)) && window[items].some(text => 
      tag.textContent.includes(text)) || (food.length < 1 && 
      window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text))) ? "block" :"none"
```

But that looks terrible to a new code reader. For the sake of juniors in the team, stick with the current way please ?

Answer (score 0):

To have a ternary operator you need  `?` and `:`. Pseudocode:

```
if (condition) { block1 } else { block2 } => condition ? block1 : block2
```

Condition: `food.length > 0`

Block 1: `food.some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)) && window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text))`

Block 2: `window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text))`

So this should work:

```
if (food.length > 0 ? food.some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)) && window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)) : window[items].some(text => tag.textContent.includes(text)))
```